# iPhone 6 - no photos/videos in "Recently Deleted" Album but storage settings displaying that I have over 19GB of photos in "Recently Deleted" Album

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, settings, album

As mentioned in the title, I have over 19gb of storage taken up according to the iPhone Storage settings, as shown:

[image: Recently Deleted Album 19gb]

However, I have already deleted all my photos and videos in the "Recently Deleted" Album as shown:

[image]

I also tried to click "Empty" beside the "Recently Deleted" Album under the iPhone Storage settings, a loading circle appears but eventually nothing happens:

[image]

I have tried connecting my phone to my computer and the only photos remaining are the ones I did not delete. I could not find any traces of deleted photos in any folders.

My iPhone 6 is updated to the latest 12.4 iOS, although I believe the issue has already persisted for a few years, but I didn't give any thought to it until now.

Any advice or solutions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried logging into icloud.com and checking the recently deleted folder there for any content?

Comment: I'd be tempted to do the 'ol backup, wipe the phone, restore the phone, routine and see if that fixes the issue...

Comment: There's something very buggy about the Recently Deleted folder. I have iphone 6 with latest ios 12.4. I can't even empty my Recently Deleted folder. I tried from both `Recently Deleted album > Select > Delete All`, as well as `Settings > iphone Storage > Empty Recently Deleted`. Both just hung and did nothing. Now I have 5000 blank images in my Recently Deleted album.

Comment: I fiddled around with Camera/Photos, and was able to get multi-select delete Recently Deleted photos to work again. So I did batches of 500 and was able to remove all 5000 Recently Deleted photos. However, I ended up in the same situation as you: 0 Recently Deleted photos and 0 photos, but Photos is still taking up 17 GB storage. When I tried to enable Amazon Photos sync, it still tried (but failed) to sync 5000 photos (it took hours), so obviously they were not deleted cleanly off the phone. Amazon Photo sync fails, so I have no choice but to factory reset the iPhone!